# ¿Qué hace exactamente este doble for?

Tags: python, array, numpy

El siguiente código lo que hace es aplanar cualquier array en Python con numpy pero, quisiera entender exactamente como lo hace.

El código es el siguiente:

```
flatten = []
for i in A:
    for j in i:
        flatten.append(j)

print(flatten)
```

Comment: que seria A??? como esta definido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende de que sea A, pero básicamente lo que haces con ese doble loop es recorrer todos los elementos de A, y para cada elemento de A recorre todos sus subíndices o subelementos.
Es decir, supongamos que A es un array 3D, un array compuesto por más arrays, pues con este loop se recorrería todos los arrays de A y en cada array de A se recorrerian todos los elementos de dentro de los mismos.